# Android - Saving beacon RSSI to Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, beacon

**Problem:** I want to store the *rssi* value of different beacons in the firebase database, but the rssi values of all my beacons gets stored under one beacon (see image).

[image]

**What I have done:**
I'm working with the Estimote Proximity beacons. I have used NFC to connect to the beacons and save the beaconId and a beaconName which the user chooses.

I then have a activity where I scan for beacons nearby, so I get the beaconName (beacon1 and beacon2)

```
databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                 beaconName = data.getKey();
             }
        }
```

and use that when scanning to insert to the database:

```
mBeaconManager.setLocationListener(new BeaconManager.LocationListener() {
   @Override
   public void onLocationsFound(List<EstimoteLocation> locations) {
       for (EstimoteLocation beacon : locations) {
           if (RegionUtils.computeProximity(beacon) == Proximity.IMMEDIATE) {
                  arrayList.add(beacon.rssi);
                      databaseReference.child(beaconName).child("rssi").setValue(arrayList);
                    }

                }

            }
    });
```

**Suggestions?** Do any of you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: What do you expect `beaconName` to be?  It's only going to have one value after your database listener loop finishes.

Comment: @DougStevenson you're right regarding `beaconName` only having one value. Should I instead assign the `data.getKey()` to an array so I get both keys `beacon1` and `beacon2`?